# How to calculate average index place for each item

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to estimate average rank of the items by multiple categories in pandas dataframe, but do not know how to do this

Let's say we have the next dataframe which rates items in different categories. The items are sorted already by descending item's score in each column.

```
Index Safety Performance Capability

  0   item_1   item_3      item_1
  1   item_3   item_2      item_2
  2   item_4   item_1      item_3
  3   item_2   item_4      item_4
```

What I need is the overall rating of items based on their indexes in all categories, so the overall in this case will look smth like this:

```
Total

item_1
item_3
item_2
item_4
```

Comment: You need to define the weight here

Comment: weight is the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the weight is `index` using `melt` the `groupby` with `mean` of the Index

```
s=df.reset_index().melt('Index').groupby('value')['Index'].mean().sort_values()
s
Out[14]: 
value
item_1    0.666667
item_3    1.000000
item_2    1.666667
item_4    2.666667
Name: Index, dtype: float64
df['Total']=s.index
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `stack`+`groupby`+`sum` (can also use `mean` like wen)

```
df.set_index('Index').stack().reset_index().groupby(0).Index.sum().sort_values()
```

Outputs

```
item_1    2
item_3    3
item_2    5
item_4    8
Name: Index, dtype: int64
```